# LINQ sorting on objects on subobject

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects (Books) and those objects look like this:

```
Class Book
{
    public string book_Name {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string,string> book_Dictionary {get; set;}

    public Book(string book_Name, Dictionary<string,string> book_Dictionary)
    {
        this.book_Name = book.Name;
        this.book_Dictionary = book_Dictionary;
    }
}
```

I compile these Book objects into a list of books, so I have

```
  List<Book> library;
```

I want to go through this list and sort out any duplicate book objects. (A duplicate book would be a book that has the same *name* and *dictionary* as any other book in the list).

To do this, I am trying the following:

```
    private List<Book> removeDuplicateBooks(List<Book> library)
    {
        List<Book> distinctLibrary = library
           .GroupBy(x => new { x.book_Name, x.book_Dictionary })
           .Select(g => g.First())
           .ToList();

        return distinctLibrary;
    }
```

However, it looks like this does not remove duplicates... my guess is that the groupBy is somehow getting thrown for a loop because one of the dictionary?

EDIT: To remove ambiguity -- When I say it does not remove duplicates, I mean the distinctLibrary that is returned is the same as the library (even though the library does contain duplicate books).

EDIT: Examples:
Lets say my library contains the following Book objects:

**bookNum1:**

```
name: "book1",

dictionary: {
   Key:"foo"
   Value:"bar"

   Key:"balloon"
   Value:"red"
}
```

**bookNum2:**

```
name: "book2",

dictionary: {
   Key:"foo"
   Value:"bar"

   Key:"balloon"
   Value:"red"
}
```

**bookNum3:**

```
name: "book1",

dictionary: {
   Key:"foo"
   Value:"bar"

   Key:"balloon"
   Value:"red"
}
```

**bookNum4:**

```
name: "book1",

dictionary: {
   Key:"fooey"
   Value:"bar"

   Key:"balloon"
   Value:"red"
}
```

If I put this library through the removeDuplicates() function, I would expect a library to return containing the following book objects: bookNum1, bookNum2, bookNum4

Comment: Out of interest, what is the reason for the dictionary? What is your definiton of an equal book-dictionary?

Comment: Can you include a few test cases in the question and your desired result for each? For example it's hard to tell what you're classing as the same dictionary, literally the same one by reference or two that contain the same entries?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It is basically used as a tuple. It stores 2 value pairs, but for other parts in the code I guess it's nifty to store it into a dictionary.

Comment: @Equalsk I added a test case to the question. A duplicate dictionary would contain the same keys/values in the same order as another dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries don't guarantee order so don't rely on that. You might consider an `OrderedDictionary` if that's required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` doesn't override `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, that's why `GroupBy` will just compare references. All those dictionaries are created with `new Dictionary...` , so they are different references. You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Book` and/or implement `IEquatable<Book>` and/or provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Book>`(for `GroupBy`).

```
public class Book : IEquatable<Book>
{
    public string BookName { get; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> BookDictionary { get; }

    public Book(string bookName, Dictionary<string, string> bookDictionary)
    {
        this.BookName = bookName;
        this.BookDictionary = bookDictionary ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bookDictionary));
    }

    public bool Equals(Book other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (!string.Equals(BookName, other.BookName))
            return false;
        if (BookDictionary.Count != other.BookDictionary.Count)
            return false;
        return BookDictionary.All(kv => other.BookDictionary.ContainsKey(kv.Value) 
                                     && other.BookDictionary[kv.Key] == kv.Value);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((Book) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int dictHash = 17;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in this.BookDictionary)
            {
                dictHash = dictHash * 23 + kv.Key.GetHashCode();
                dictHash = dictHash * 23 + (kv.Value ?? "").GetHashCode();
            }

            return ((BookName != null ? BookName.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ dictHash;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `Book` itself as key in dictionaries or as argument for `GroupBy`:

```
List<Book> distinctLibrary = library
   .GroupBy(book => book)
   .Select(g => g.First())
   .ToList();
```

and now you could even use the more efficient (and simpler):

```
List<Book> distinctLibrary = library.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of why it wasn't working. So many times on here people will throw code at you. With this I can learn something! I've accepted the answer in good faith - will try to get this implemented in mean time.

Comment: @Christopher: Side-note: Now you could also use `List<Book> distinctLibrary = library.Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: Update: working like a charm :) this is very neat!! And I like this solution the most because this gives a lot of flexibility as to how I define likeness between two objects.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to compare a custom type you have to implement the IComparable interface. This then allows for determining if an object is "greater than" or "less than" or equal.

How you implement this depends on your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

@TimSchmelter answer looks quite nice but I also would like to share my approach (I think and do it simple :) ) Also I can get the critics on the way especially from @Tim Schmelter.

Main method and dummy data that you shared.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "foo", "bar"},
            { "balloon", "red"}
        };

        Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "fooey", "bar"},
            { "balloon", "red"}
        };

        var books = new List<Book>();
        books.Add(new Book("book1", dict));
        books.Add(new Book("book2", dict));
        books.Add(new Book("book1", dict));
        books.Add(new Book("book1", dict2));

        var distinctLib = RemoveDuplicateBooks(books);
    }
```

Linq query;

```
    private static List<Book> RemoveDuplicateBooks(List<Book> library)
    {
        var distinctLib = from c in library
                        group c by new
                        { 
                            c.book_Name,
                            c.book_Dictionary
                        } into temp
                        select new Book()
                        {
                            book_Name = temp.First().book_Name,
                            book_Dictionary = temp.First().book_Dictionary
                        };

        return distinctLib.ToList();

    }
```

Return;

**Book1**, **Book2** and **Book4**

Comment: Could you explain how the select is able to distinguish a distinct dictionary? I'm just having trouble understanding that part.

Comment: Select is not eliminating. in while we are grouping data eliminating. when group by executing the same book removed from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a method for removing duplicate Books, i suggest this:

```
private void removeDuplicateBooks(List<Book> library)
    {
        foreach(Book b in library) {
            // put book b in a new library
            List<Book> distinctLibrary = library.FindAll(b);
            // if you find more than once the book
            if(distinctLibrary.Count > 1) {
                 // delete all copies of b and keep only one
                 library.RemoveAll(b);
                 library.Add(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: this method doesn't return a new library, only cleans the deafault library.